# How did Van Helsing not turn into a vampire in the movie Dracula 2000?

Tags: plot-explanation, dracula-2000

Paying homage to **Wes Craven** who recently passed away, I have a question about one of my favorite vampire movies that Craven was an Executive Producer, *Dracula 2000*.

In the movie, Van Helsing is the "keeper" of Dracula.  Van Helsing must be able to survive in order to keep Dracula entombed for long periods of time. He puts leeches on Dracula's body and then injects Dracula's blood into his own through the leeches. This process keeps Van Helsing immortal, but only for a time because he has to continually repeat the process.

How did Van Helsing not turn into a vampire after this process?

Comment: The hot bride says you must be chosen. Most vampire lore requires more than just a bite to turn. Injecting his blood isn't enough.

Comment: Because she's the one that said it, in the police station. Before she eats the detective and dracula eats the doctor.

Comment: Depends on the lore. Some you need to be completely drained. And then given/drink the vamps blood (most). Some require it to happen over multiple nights (Book Dracula) Other require the vamp and the victim to be buried together (Trublood) Some just need to drink a vampire's blood. Underworld uses an virus/infection/science method so just a bite is needed. Some you must be born one. Others it's a satanic/devil worship ritual. Or be cursed. I Am Legend uses genetic plague/bio warfare that created vampires.

Comment: See http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurVampiresAreDifferent if you have hours to burn.

Comment: @cde Thanks for the link!  That helps explain alot.  Very helpful :)

Comment: But the movie doesn't actually follow the book much. Lucy was turned in a single night. Like an hour, not over the course of several days. There's no ghoul/renfeild.

Comment: Provided a better answer I think.

Comment: Dang, I'll have to go back and watch this again. I could have sworn there was a scene where he explained to someone how he was so old (probably the apprentice guy), and he specifically said something like "in small quantities" or "just enough".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie lacks any explicit showing of *siring*, the creation of a vampire. All we see is biting. The vamps at the beginning were bit on the plane before it crashed, and the Second Bride, the Reporter Solina afterwards. Lucy the Third Bride, is also shown just being bit.

Solina makes a vague reference to being chosen (as a lover) while she is in an interrogation room at a police station. Soon after, she breaks through and the movie implies she feeds on the Detective, while Dracula feeds on the Doctor. We don't see either of those two, or if anyone else in the police station who may have been killed, turned into vamps later in the movie. We also see that Prof. Van Helsing was killed, supposedly drained by the 3 Brides, but he also remains dead. Nor do we see the cameraman that Dracula attacks before he turned Solina.

The closest thing we see is the dream sequence/flashback when Dracula turns Mary and shows her how he was created. After biting her in the real world, she also drinks his blood in the dream sequence. Given that we are then shown a flashback to Dracula's disciple days, can't be sure if it is required for turning into a vampire or just the flashback or if it even happened in the real world.

**So conclusively, the only thing that was shown is that Dracula bit them, and some turned while others might not have (or were completely ignored afterwards), and it might have to be a conscious choosing on Dracula's part on who turns.**

One possible clue is that in the end, Dracula releases Mary of her vampirism.

> I *guhgrr* release **gurchoakingnoises** you.
>   *Mary's pupils go from blood red, to white, to normal*

He had magical control over her vampirism and could release it by will alone, indicates that turning people into vampires could also be purely done by choice.

Dracula, as written by Bram Stoker, required multiple days (nights) of feeding on Lucy before she was turned, so it cannot be used as a base reference.

Comment: @steelerfan well, he succeeded in turning her. Her eyes changed, her fangs grew, and she survived a fall from a building. Then he releases her turning her human again. There was no try.